# Npm install errror during docker container building

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I created very simple docker file for my nodejs web application:

```
FROM node:8.11.4
FROM mysql:latest

WORKDIR /ess-explorer
COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN cd config && cp config.json.example config.json && cp database.json.example database.json && cd ../

RUN npm run migrate

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "dev"]
```

And `docker.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:

  essblockexplorer:
    container_name: ess-explorer
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    privileged: true
    ports:
       - 3000:3000
       - 3010:3010

  db:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '123'

volumes:
  db-data:
```

After command `docker-compose -f docker.yml build` evey time I've got an error 
`Step 5/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in d3644d792807
/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
ERROR: Service 'essblockexplorer' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 127`
What am i doing wrong? I found similar issues but i didnt find the real solution for solving this problem

Comment: @Veve I copied example from official nodejs website https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Comment: I think you can't have two `FROM` like this. So only the mysql image is used  used and it doesn't have npm. Take a look at https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: @L.Faros I didnt get any errors while installing two containers and i can see images ```mysql               latest              2dd01afbe8df        5 days ago          485MB``` and ```node                8.11.4              8198006b2b57        7 weeks ago         673MB```

Comment: Yes, that doesn't throw any error and it pull both of the images, but the commands after the `FROM` will use only the latest image, not both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `mysql` image in your Dockerfile at all; ideally your app container (`essblockexplorer`) accesses the db container (`db`) via a NodeJS client.  All you need to do is;

1. Remove the `FROM mysql:latest` line from your Dockerfile.
2. Access the MySQL database via a NodeJS client using (`db`) as the hostname (this is automatically loaded as an alias into your container).